# How to use Dispatch Group in a loop with asynchronous Function Swift?

Tags: swift, for-loop, dispatchgroup

I have checked all the questions regarding this topic but none of them helped.
I have a code like below. Now as soon as the code enters the `for id in stringArray` loop, it gets executed for the `stringArray.count` times without even entering the firestore asynchronous part. That's understandable, but not my requirement. I want `myGroup.notify` to be executed after the loop and the asynchronous code  has finished. But as loop finishes readily and so `myGroup.notify` gets called even when asynchronous is yet to be finished. So, basically may be I am asking here to place the `myGroup.enter` and `myGroup.leave` at correct places. Thanks!

MyCode:

```
func Promise_searchedDataFromDB(stringArray:[String]) {
    for id in stringArray {
        myGroup.enter()
    collectionRef.getDocuments { (querySnapshot, error) in
        if error != nil {
            return
        }
        else {
               guard let snapshot = querySnapshot else {return}
               for document in snapshot.documents {
                
                let myData = document.data()
                if StaticVariable == true {
             
                    self.typeOfListing = myData["Type"] as? String ?? "Not Found"
                    self.charges = Int(myData["Charges"] as? String ?? "Not Found") ?? 0
                    self.nameOfListing = myData["Title"] as? String ?? "Not Found"
                    self.currency = myData["Currency"] as? String ?? "Not Found"
                    self.days = myData["Days"] as? String ?? "Not Found"
                    self.details = myData["Description"] as? String ?? "Not Found"
                    self.cityName = myData["City"] as? String ?? "Ghost"
                    
                    let dataArray = CellComponents(image: UIImage(named: "b")!, typeOfListing: self.typeOfListing , charges: self.charges, rating: 4.1, nameOfListing: self.nameOfListing , cityName: self.cityName, detail: self.details, currency: self.currency, days: self.days)
                    self.ArrayToHoldSearchedListing.append(dataArray)
                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                }
              }
            }
          }

             myGroup.leave()
       }
        
        myGroup.notify(queue: .main) {
            print("All done")
        }
   }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Leave within the async block not outside of it ... and enter should be equal to leave so put it in defer statement to always execute before leaving the scope

```
  func Promise_searchedDataFromDB(stringArray:[String]) {
     for id in stringArray {
         myGroup.enter()
     collectionRef.getDocuments { (querySnapshot, error) in
        defer{  myGroup.leave() }
        
         if error != nil {
             return
         }
         else {
                guard let snapshot = querySnapshot else {return}
                for document in snapshot.documents {
                 
                 let myData = document.data()
                 if StaticVariable == true {
              
                     self.typeOfListing = myData["Type"] as? String ?? "Not Found"
                     self.charges = Int(myData["Charges"] as? String ?? "Not Found") ?? 0
                     self.nameOfListing = myData["Title"] as? String ?? "Not Found"
                     self.currency = myData["Currency"] as? String ?? "Not Found"
                     self.days = myData["Days"] as? String ?? "Not Found"
                     self.details = myData["Description"] as? String ?? "Not Found"
                     self.cityName = myData["City"] as? String ?? "Ghost"
                     
                     let dataArray = CellComponents(image: UIImage(named: "b")!, typeOfListing: self.typeOfListing , charges: self.charges, rating: 4.1, nameOfListing: self.nameOfListing , cityName: self.cityName, detail: self.details, currency: self.currency, days: self.days)
                     self.ArrayToHoldSearchedListing.append(dataArray)
                     self.tableView.reloadData()
                 }
               }
             }
           }

            
        }
         
         myGroup.notify(queue: .main) {
             print("All done")
         }
    }
```

Comment: O yes sir! That worked perfect! That `defer` thing was new to me and very helpful too. Thanks!

Comment: you are welcom @FahadAli... accept answer if it works .. happy coding =)